# Authenticate Username and password from a header in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

**I am a beginner and just trying hard to learn laravel**

I work with device API and this API doesn't provide authentication facility,

So, I want to authenticate User from HTTP header [When the page load, the first user have to enter Username and password into the prompt box; if the user is valid then and then the page will be load]

My best efforts and research includes:

**My Code**

```
$hearderauth = $request->header();
```

**and I get this information from the header**

Array ( [host] => Array ( [0] => localhost:8000 ) [connection] => Array ( [0] => keep-alive ) [cache-control] => Array ( [0] => max-age=0 ) [upgrade-insecure-requests] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [user-agent] => Array ( [0] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36 ) [accept] => Array ( [0] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3 ) [accept-encoding] => Array ( [0] => gzip, deflate, br ) [accept-language] => Array ( [0] => en-US,en;q=0.9,ca;q=0.8 ) [cookie] => Array ( [0] => XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ikh4Tm40dFo1T2EwcjhCc1NLR2hTSnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYjVSZ25rdTh5SnEwSjZrbHRzdk05dWYxMTFrVTl0aXhMSldwbUhvMXhcL3Y5U2Y3QjJtcVpxXC9wY1pyRFdSMUJqIiwibWFjIjoiYjlkNjBmNDM2YWEzNWNjYjczZjRjZWVlYmJiNDg0NWMzMWY5NWQ2MzBiMzI2N2Y4NTI2NDJkMWM2OTc0MjEzNiJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Iml5TnZNSG1Bc0FcLzFHK1M4UXdpbE93PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkZhVFFcL1l4ZmdVNVluTFBkbVNPc2QzU0lsclp2QklBeGZyanZqa25WZ3d2T3pMR3QxSTgxSXU5OXA1d2FNYXZQIiwibWFjIjoiYmZlOWJhYzhlMDM1ZDFmZTY4ODAxYjk4N2Q0MWIzNmNjOThmOGEzZTNmOGIzM2E4Y2Q3YmQ1YTg1NzIyM2EzZiJ9 ) )

**How should I pass username and password to this header or 
what should write in the controller to authenticate the user?**

Guide me how to face this situation?

In short -> authentication should be done via HTTP header

Comment: Search for Laravel Passport, you might not need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @EliasSoares I will look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel includes authentication scaffolding for front-end applications as we all know.

But there's another Laravel product called Passport which works with Laravel to provide API Authentication options.

I can't tell if you're trying to authorise regular users in your front-end or if you're building an API without front-end authentication.

Either way, I recommend you check the documentation on [Basic Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authentication-quickstart) and [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#introduction).